# "Without any problem" or "without any problems"

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is the correct form:
**"Without any problem"** or **"Without any problems"**?

Comment: I wish we could also include "without a problem" and "without problem" here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either will do. It's actually pretty amazing just how interchangeably they're used:

[image]

Comment: What have you used to create that plot?

Comment: @FormlessCloud It's Google Ngram Viewer. https://books.google.com/ngrams

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. You can use either one.

Answer (score 3):

**Any** means one or more, which means that both options mentioned by you, are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Normally one would just say *without problem*, skipping the *any* altogether. It doesn’t really add anything to speak of, and just makes the phrase longer.

But I certainly wouldn’t call  *without any problems* (**or** *with no problems*) ‘wrong’.

Also, you can swap in *trouble* for *problem* in all those phrases, and you get the same answer; think also of *no trouble found*.

Comment: I'm not sure who your "one" is, exactly; my experience indicates and Ngram confirms that "without any problem" and "without any problems" are *individually* about twice as common as "without problem": http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+problem%2Cwithout+any+problems%2C+without+any+problem&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3